# Java hashmap with a lock for idempotent writes but not reads

Tags: java, concurrency, hashmap

Is this considered threadsafe?

```
private final Map<String, Boolean> map = new HashMap<>();
private final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();

public boolen test(String key, boolean val) {
    if(map.get(key)!=null) {
        return map.get(key);
    }

    try {
        lock.lock();
        map.put(key, val);
        return map.get(key);
    }finally{
        lock.unlock();
    }

}
```

My concern is map resizing causing unknown issues, as there are no guarantees here

The writes are all idempotent (i.e. every key/val pair is the same forever)

Comment: Have you looked at [`ConcurrentHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html)?

Comment: I do not want to use concurrenthashmap, I am only interested in if this is valid or not

Comment: Your concern is justified, The code is not thread-safe.  It's unsafe even if no resize occurs, since the 'put' may be modifying the list of entries in the same bucket a 'get' is traversing.

Comment: @accessviolation I think you're overstating the case. The [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#:~:text=If%20multiple%20threads%20access%20a%20hash%20map%20concurrently%2C%20and%20at%20least%20one%20of%20the%20threads%20modifies%20the%20map%20structurally%2C%20it%20must%20be%20synchronized%20externally.) only say there's a thread-safety issue when making structural changes. That said, OP is making structural changes if I'm understanding correctly.

Comment: I don't believe that `get` will ever throw a ConcurrentModificationException, or return the wrong result (other than not seeing a value which is in the process of being inserted)

Comment: @tgdavies That doesn't mean it's safe. I believe there's an old HashMap implementation that could set off an infinite loop if `get()` was called during resizing.

Comment: What's the point of calling `get()` after putting the value? What's the point of returning a value at all if it never changes? Why is your method `void`?

Comment: fixed the return type

Comment: @shmosel - surely adding an element to a bucket is a structural change. You're extending a linked list.

Comment: It is not safe and can cause infinite loops due to stale reads ([article](https://mailinator.blogspot.com/2009/06/beautiful-race-condition.html)).

Comment: the linked article is over a race condition with multiple threads writing; the write in this example is synchronized.

Comment: @accessviolation That's what I'm saying. But it's not necessarily unsafe when the entry already exists. Though maybe I'm misunderstanding what you meant by "resize".

Comment: I meant resizing the bucket-vector, i.e., rehashing.  Not the simple addition of an element to an existing bucket.

Answer (score 0):

No.  This code is not thread-safe.

If the `put` call adds a new entry to the `HashMap` then that is a *structural change*.  The [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashMap.html) states that external synchronization is required.  That means that both writers and readers must synchronize ...

The javadoc doesn't distinguish between structural changes that do or don't trigger resizes.

---

Note that

> The writes are all idempotent (i.e. every key/val pair is the same forever)

is false.  In your example, key/value pairs are not the same for ever.  Even if you always `put` the same value for any given key, there are two states; the key is absent, or the key is present with a given value.  Changing from the absent state to the present state for a given key is a structural change to the `HashMap`.

---

@shmoel commented:

> I believe there's an old `HashMap` implementation that could set off an infinite loop if `get()` was called during resizing.

That is consistent with the javadocs.  A resize of the `HashMap` can only be triggered by a structural change; i.e. addition or removal of an entry.

I don't think that you would get an infinite loop these days, but you may find that the `get` returns an incorrect result; e.g. a result that is different to what you should get if there was *proper* external synchronization.

Comment: I think, the documentation’s wording is misleading. Even when there are no structural changes, there is no guaranty that a write by one thread is visible to another thread.

Comment: I always thought that too ... but I was lazy.  I didn't read the source code to try and work out what the actual behavior would be for a "nonstructural" change.